# c# parse date time with timezone

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, parsing, timezone

How can we parse date time with time zone.

```
<TIMESTAMP_UTC>20180523160000</TIMESTAMP_UTC>
<TIMEZONE>UTC+8</TIMEZONE>
```

this should convert as in 2018-05-24 00:00:00.
I tried couple of things but could not succeed.
I tried the below command but it throws an error.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20180523160000+08:00", "yyyyMMddHHmmssZhhmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Do you know how we can parse this with DateTime Parse methods.

Comment: Sounds like DateTimeOffset could be handy here

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`

```
var date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("20180523160000+08:00", "yyyyMMddHHmmsszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this seems to parse, but I wonder if I need to inverse the time zone. What that data means 2018-05-24  00:00:00 I think, but what I get back in UTC is [23.05.2018 08:00:00 +00:00]. That is odd.

Comment: @hazimdikenli I tried to parse the date by passing `20180524000000+00:00` i get `2018-05-24 00:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DateTimeOffset.Parse()` instead of `DateTime.Parse()` as `DateTimeOffset` stores timezone info.

You can refer to the following MSDN link for more details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could invert the sign of your timezone and then parse it with

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "20180523160000UTC-8",
    "yyyyMMddHHmmssUTCz",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But if this is a good approach is probably questionable.